# CMD: clip command issue

Tags: cmd, clipboard

I have found a weird issue using the clip command of Widows CMD.
I created a simple text file containing this text:
`^.*A{0,0}.*$`
Then I ran the command `clip < PATH_TO_THE_TEXT_FILE` in CMD.
Finally, I tried pasting the copied text into text editors such as Notepad and Notepad++, and what I got was some weird Japanese characters. This issue can be reproduced every time and on different PCs.
Can you please tell me what is causing this issue and how can I make the clip command copy the actual text in the text file, and not the weird Japanese characters?

Comment: Save the text file as ANSI or OEM.

Comment: I tried but it did not work for me. Did that work for you? Can you please tell me more exactly how to save the file in those charsets? For example, if I would use Java, which charset name should I use? I tried cp1252, which is supposed to be ANSI, and it did not work.

Comment: Use Notepad to save it as Ansi. Don't use other editors.

Answer (score 0):

> what is causing this

Incorrect encoding conversion, ASCII String -> bytes -> UTF-16 String

```js
// JavaScript code to emulate this
bytes =  new TextEncoder("UTF-8").encode( '^.*A{0,0}.*$' )
new TextDecoder("UTF-16LE").decode( bytes )
```

> how can I make the clip command copy the actual text

<del>`type PATH_TO_THE_TEXT_FILE | clip`</del>
Sorry, update the answer.

Update: `clip` works if there is a newline in the end of the file.

Comment: Yes, clip works if there is a newline at the end of the text file, I can see that, but it also copies the newline with the text, as expected. And I don't want that to happen. I would want to be able to only copy the text itself, as it is, to clipboard.

Comment: If it's ok to use powershell, then `powershell.exe -command "type PATH_TO_THE_TEXT_FILE | set-clipboard"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what 7cc said, I figued out how to make it work.
I need to create the text file using the encoding UTF-16LE, and then it works.